# Application Root in MVC App?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having some problems with an MVC app that uses logic based off data driven URLs (for routing) if my application is deployed to anywhere else other than the domain root.

I tried using various Request.Url properties to no avail.

Let's say I deploy my app to `www.mydomain.com/myapp/` or even `www.mydomain.com/myapp/subapp/`. In these cases how can I get `/myapp/` and `/myapp/subapp/` respectively. Even if the user is on a totally different page such as `/myapp/Users/Recent/`?

I need that so I can prefix all the data driven URLs so my app still works when not on the domain root.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath`.

Note that all of the `Url.*` helpers will do this for you.

Comment: Routing table will work with the full path, right? That is, if the app is deployed at `...\must\go\deeper\theApp`, routing rules will apply starting from `theApp`?

Comment: Just a minor type but its AppDomainAppVirtualPath. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreCalil I do custom routing for static content and across multiple areas so it deviates slightly from the default rules.

Comment: FYI, you can test all of this if you are using IIS Express. Go to the properties of your MVC project, click Web tab, and under IIS Express, there is a "Project Url" text box. You can add as many subapp levels as you want here. It will prompt you to create a new virtual directory, click yes. Then when you run, you can get to the app root from http://localhost:nnnnn/must/go/deeper.

Comment: @DOTang Ok, but the deploy path does not modify how routing rules work, right?

Comment: @AndreCalil: Yes.  All ASP.Net paths are relative to the AppDomain route.

Comment: @danludwig: I think you can do that in Cassini too.